# How can i remove double quotes in cmd title

Tags: python, cmd

I am writing a python game and im done with it, now i just want to add a title to the cmd window, i tried using `os.sytem("title Golf Game | by Boic#8506")` that didnt work as "|" is a pipeline in cmd so i changed it to `os.sytem("title \"Golf Game | by Boic#8506\"")` then the "|" came in the title but then my title had quotes in it which i didnt like so my question is how can i remove these quotes from my title or is there any other way to do this in python.

Also i know i should use subprocces and not os.system but i am used to it.

Comment: What is the result if you *do* use `subprocess`? `subprocess.run(["title", "Golf Game | by Boic#8506"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the inner quotes, and escape the pipe symbol (|) by using the `^` symbol:

```
os.system("title Golf Game ^| by Boic#8506")
```